# Blog post URL + post title in mailto

Tags: html, url, blogs, mailto

I want to add "share this page via email" button in my blog post page. In the blog post template, this is what I currently have:

```
<a 
href="mailto:?subject=Post title from XYZ blog&cc=me@xyzblog.com&body=URL+to+page%2C+short+description&<?php
echo curPageURL(); ?>">Share this page via email</a>
```

How can I make the actual post title and page URL variables correctly appear in the email output?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help someone developing in WordPress.

Here is what I added to my template file (.php)

```
<a href="mailto:someone@site.com?subject=<?php wp_title()?>&body=<?php 
print(urlencode(get_permalink())); ?>"> Email this blog post... </a>
```

Here is an article that shows how to use the Mailto attributes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="#" id="mail">Share this page</a>
```

using

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("mail").onclick=function() {
    this.href='mailto:?subject='+
    document.title+'&cc=me@xyzblog.com&body='+
    document.URL+'%0D%0A'+
    document.querySelector(".s22_richTextContainer").innerText++'%0D%0A'+
    '<img src="'+document.querySelector(".s25img img").src+'" />'
  }
}
```

You many have to throw a few encodeURIComponent in there

Comment: Thank you, mplngjan! I've managed to get to this status: http://michaelpashbyantiq.wixsite.com/draft/single-post/2016/08/29/A-George-III-Bachelors-Chest-of-Diminutive-Proportions  See the "email this page to a friend" link at bottom of page

Comment: Is it possible to also make the title & first image of the blog post appear in the body of mailto email output?